# Swift string from optional Double

Tags: swift

Is there a shortcut to specify placeholder text when the value is nil in Swift?

Right now I do:

```
let myText:String!
if myDouble != nil{
  myText = "\(myDouble!)"
}else{
  myText = "Value not provided"
}
```

That works, but it's very annoying to have to do that all the time. Is there a way to do something like

```
let myText:String = "\(myDouble ?? "Value no provided")"
```

That fails because it wants a default Double value, but I really want a String value.

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, then _refactor_ and make a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `map` and nil-coalescing:

```
let myText = myDouble.map { String($0) } ?? "Value not provided"
```

If `myDouble` is `nil`, the result of `map` is `nil` and the result is the value after the `??`.

If `myDouble` is not `nil`, the result is the output of the `map` which creates a string from the `Double`.

For more details, please see the documentation for the `map` function of the `Optional` enumeration in the Swift standard library.

Comment: @Teejay I was in the middle of adding more explanation.

Comment: @rmaddy I mean unclear to code readers, not SO readers. `map` is usually used for collections.

Comment: @Teejay I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. Anyone that knows Swift can read that one line of code. If you have a specific question, ask.

Comment: @rmaddy Anyone that know Swift very well. For example, I never used `map` on anything different from a collection. This just works because `myDouble` is an Optional, that in Swift is treated as an enumeration. Absolutely tricky.

Comment: @rmaddy Check out this: http://blog.xebia.com/the-power-of-map-and-flatmap-of-swift-optionals/. At the beginning it states: "At first, this might look odd because we're calling a function on an optional."

Comment: @Teejay "I never used map on anything different from a collection." And I never used to do my taxes before I was 18. Perhaps it's time to start?

Comment: _"Anyone that know Swift very well"_ Well, congratulations, you now know Swift a little better!

Comment: @Teejay Some programmers also don't know what functions, or classes are. I'm not going to write code without functions or classes to appease this lowest common denominator. Functions, classes, and Optional.map are tools. They're useful at solving some problems. When I encounter a problem that they're useful at solving, I'll use them.

Comment: I see. As a multi-language programmer, I tend to make my code very clear to anyone reading it. Swift is so revolutionary, so this is really difficult sometimes. And they continuously add very specific constructs, e.g.`guard`. Unfortunately, Microsoft's C# started to follow this trend as well.. version 7 is full of absolutely strange constructs, that can be so unclear to new readers.

Comment: @Teejay Programming languages don't optimize for clarity to the uninitiated. If that was the goal, we'd all be using python or basic. You should not write to a lowest common denominator, just out of fear of confusing someone who doesn't know the language. This would just lead you to write crap code in every langauge

Comment: @Teejay Those "absolutely strange" constructs solve problems people have. Completion-handler based threading is incredibly messy. `async`/`await` was made to address it. Often, people need functions need to return multiple things, without warranting a dedicated struct, or the heap-allocation overhead and poor member naming of `System.Tuple`. So they added native tuple. Obviously these things will seem strange to anyone who hasn't encountered the issues they solves, but that's okay. These features weren't made for them.

Comment: I agree, but I don't think that not always using the last functions means writing crap code. Maybe some constructs help you write more concise code, but sometimes at the cost of clarity. For example, in C you could collapse assignments within an `if`, but that was truly unclear and error prone.

Comment: I don't think that `async`/`await` and `Tuple`s are absolutely strange. I refer to some statements included in C# 6.0 / 7.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163218/discussion-between-alexander-and-teejay).

Comment: No need to use a closure there. You can just pass the String initializer to the map method `map(String.init)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. I thought there was a way to just use `String.init` but I forgot the exact syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It seems reasonable to do

```
let myDouble: Double? = Double(3.0)
let myText = myDouble?.description ?? "Value not provided"
```

If `myDouble` is `nil`, then `myText` is `"Value not provided"`. If `myDouble` is not `nil`, it's assigned the string representation of the number.

Comment: It's never a good idea to show the output of `description` to a user. That's more of a debugging tool.

Comment: @rmaddy Actually, `debugDescription` exists for that.

Comment: Anyway the correct way to access object's description, as stated in reference, is by `String(describing:object)` but in this specific case it returns `Optional(number)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think good approach to this is to make Extension to optional where Double is the Wrapped element:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Double  {

    var stringValue: String {
        guard let me = self else { return "No Value Provided" }
        return "\(me)"
    }
}

// Use it like this:

myDouble.stringValue
```

Another approach could be making your custom operator like this:

```
public func ??(rhd: Double?, lhd: String) -> String {
    if let unwrapped = rhd {
        return String(unwrapped)
    } else {
        return lhd
    }
}
```

And now your line `let myText:String = "\(myDouble ?? "Value no provided")"` works.
Please let me now if you don' understand anything.

Comment: This is obscure, non-obvious behavior in both cases. I strongly advise against it.

Comment: What do you mean by non-obvious behaviour? You call stringValue on optional double either you get No Value Provided or the value in string.

Comment: By looking at `optionalDouble.stringValue`, how on earth am I to know that the result will be `"No value Provdided"` if the double is `nil`? It looks like some weird NSNumber thing, more than anything.

Comment: The question asks about this. You can make private extension in scope of your file and it will be just private for your use only.

Comment: Also the question asks for this.

Comment: Sure, but people reading `optionalDouble.stringValue` in his code won't know about this question. And sooner or later, he'll need this `Double?` -> `String` conversion in multiple places, and this code will end up in some shared utils file or library. JUst stick to `optionalDouble.map(String.init) ?? "Default value"`. It's much more idiomatic, and makes the `nil` cases much more explicit. It's also more amenable to internationalization, because the default value could be a localized string.

Comment: The broad direction of this answer, to make a function or property, is sound, but Alexander's warnings are also important.

Comment: Where did the: "This answer is too generic or not-case-specific" go?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let myText = myDouble != nil ? String(myDouble!) : "Value not provided"
```